# How to validate mutliple rows in DevExpress grid

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, devexpress, xtragrid

I have a WinForm with a read-only XtraGrid.GridControl. One column is a CheckEdit column, so the user can select/unselect rows. That row is not read-only. On a button click I want to validate selected rows and mark some of them as invalid (with the error icon). How do I do it? What I could find about grids' validation is that it can basically validate only a cell which is being edited now. And after the user has moved to another row, the previous one is considered fixed... But what I want is to validate MULTIPLE rows on some other button's click. I read that there is IDataErrorInfo interface which could help, but I don't want to rewrite the grid...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, most of validation approaches are intended to prevent user from accepting any changes in a single column or in a row. That is why it is unlikely you achieve what you want using standard validation. What if you just draw error icons manually? The GridView provides the CustomDrawCell event where you can draw the entire cell manually, and display error icons under an appropriate condition.

Comment: Thanks :) I thought about it but in the end I decided just to add error text to a cell's text and draw it with red color :)